# Is it "flotation" or "floatation"?

Tags: differences, nouns, orthography, vowels

Is the difference between *flotation* and *floatation* a US/UK difference or something else?

I think I did see *floatation* in some physics book.

Comment: +1 I never knew of the 'floatation' spelling, but find it all over Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd have to say that the difference was influenced by something else.

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flotation&allowed_in_frame=0), the **French** influenced the more widely used spelling *flotation*.

And according to the same root-[source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=floatation&allowed_in_frame=0) regarding *floatation*:

> the older, more etymological, but less popular spelling of [flotation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flotation&allowed_in_frame=0)

---

Several of these sources (will list below) all agree that *floatation* and *flotation* are **variant spellings** of one another.

[M.Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flotation)
[image: Variants of FLOTATION --- **flo·ta·tion** also **floa·ta·tion**]

[Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/floatation)
[image: a variant spelling of _flotation_ --- flotation *or* floatation]

And (my new favorite word coming up) *according* to this [source](http://members.peak.org/~jeremy/dictionaryclassic/tables/spellcat.php#other), there is no specific difference between BE and AmE regarding to *flotation/floatation* confusion. I'd like to point out, his site has similar sources to back up his findings.

Comment: I had always thought "floatation" was not the proper spelling and was a mis-spelling by people who would write "pronounciation".

Comment: +1 Wish you had summarized your findings in a short para at the end.

Answer (score 10):

I wasn’t aware of the *floatation* spelling, or that it was found in American English. The OED has only *flotation*, but with this note:

> The spelling *flotation* is not etymologically justifiable, but is more common in use, probably because it disguises the hybrid formation, so that the word appears more conformable to the general analogy of scientific terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need someone who has come across both to answer.

Comment: Um, the OED2 lists **both** spellings, and indeed lists the *floatation* spelling first. (But yes, has your note.)

Comment: In American English 'flotation' is very much more frequent than 'floatation', in the ratio 12:1 in 'American English from the Cambridge International Corpus' (Reference: P. Peters)

Comment: @tchrist: My reference was to the online OED. The Shorter OED (2002) also gives _floatation_, but as a variant spelling. It certainly seems to be the case that _flotation_ ‘is in more common use’. The COCA has 298 records for it against 12 for _floatation_. The equivalent BNC figures are 266 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

Summary:  It's Scots, laddie.

I am a British Empire Antipodean, but well versed in the mother tongue, and long in the tooth to boot, but until now had never encountered "floatation" as a word.

Google NGrams show as below, with "floatation" appearing at about 1800.

[image: A usage graph comparing "floatation" (blue) with "flotation" (red). The blue line isn't visible at all until a few tiny blips around 1850, a teeny-tiny little plateau just before 1900, and a very slight upward slope until 2000. The red line has a peak around 1580, then nothing until 1710, then a series of peaks until 1800, then an asymptotically increasing line peaking around 1925. For the remainder of the century, it drops back down to about half of that peak, with secondary peaks in 1950 and 1990 and a dip in 1975 (though it's still higher than even the 1580 aberration). With the exception of a tiny little crossover just before 1850, the red line far outstrips the blue line.]

Further searching produced a result which surprised me.  It's Scots, laddie. 
 The term "floatation" is widely used in Scotland, as opposed to the UK in general, being much more common than "flotation".
While this can be confirmed by searching the web for floatation and reading Scottish related entries, a good idea of what will be found is obtained by searching the web for

- "floatation" related_term
- flotation related_term

The quote marks around the 1st term tend to make at least Google offer fewer entries with suggested alternatives.

Some results for *floatation* and *flotation* with various related_terms are below. M = millions of hits. k = 1000's of hits.

e.g. "Australia 420 k / 10.9 M" = 420,000 hits for *floatation* and *Australia*, 2.29 million hits for *Australia* and *flotation*.

Very obviously this method has methodological deficiencies, but it is also demonstrably useful.

floatation / flotation.

All  3.69M / 10.9M
Australia 420 k  / 2.29 M
England   266k / 2.23M
Scotland  2.01 M / 445 k
USA  689 k / 3.52 M
Scottish  2.38 M / 261 K
Scots  2.327 M / 659 k
NZ  252 k / 1.18 M
"South Africa" 181k / 994 k
Wales 117 k / 341 k
"pinyin" 37k / 206 k

fwiw
 "English" 600 k / 1.92 M
 ie adding the quotes around "English" did not greatly affect the result.

One could go on :-).
 But the two Scots related entries are about  4:1 and 9:1 in favour of *floatation*.
 All others and overall result are strongly biased towards *flotation*.

An examination of some of the Scots related pages shows widespread use of "floatation" in contexts that would be foreign to most people reading this posting.

BUT:

Russian  2.84 M / 864 k  - A Scottish translator writer is suspected :-)